# How to type こんにちは (not こんにちわ) with windows Japanese keyboard

Tags: input-method

Google spells こんにちは as こんにちは but when I type "konnnichiwa" I've got  こんにちわ and if I do space I've got : コンニチワ ...

maybe don't need to trust google here ? or there is some another way to write it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「は」 is always entered into an IME as "ha", even if it is romanized as "wa" due to use as a particle.

Comment: so must I type konnnichiha for こんにちは ?

Comment: Yes, although there possibly may be variants for 「ん」 and 「ち」 ("n'" and "ti" respectively). You won't really have to worry about those though.

Comment: Same goes for こんばんは, by the way.